# how to implement inheritance in django to simplify and remove data duplication?

Tags: python, django, inheritance

i have this model design implementation using inheritance, so that editor and author are inheriting from person, i've done this so that i wouldn't have duplicate data when an author becomes an editor or vice versa, and of course to make it easier to list if i want to display all people regardless of their job description (since they are all persons).

now ive created my code to do this in django, and setup my admin.py to be able to add data to it quickly, my problem is its not doing what i think it should be doing,i thought when i add an author, ill just pick person values from the dropdown list and save it as author, but its showing firstname, middlename, lastname textboxes etc. instead

my problem is how would make it so that ill just pick from a dropdown so that when i save it, the id of the selected item from the dropdown will be saved instead of the whole filename, middlename, lastname etc..(which currently the one showing when running)

i have inspected the generated sql create command for these classes and i found out that editor and author classes makes person their FK, so im guessing its possible but still hadnt found the exact solution for this.

below are the code i wrote that contains some problems. Thanks a lot.

```
# model.py
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('0','unknown'),
        ('1','male'),
        ('2','female'),
    )
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middlename = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=0)
    other_info = models.TextField(blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        fullname = self.lastname + ', ' + self.firstname[0]+'.'
        return fullname.encode("utf-8")

class Editor(Person):   
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    years_experience = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        fullname = self.lastname + ', ' + self.firstname[0]+'.'
        return fullname.encode("utf-8")

class Author(Person):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __str__(self):
        fullname = self.lastname + ', ' + self.firstname[0]+'.'
        return fullname.encode("utf-8")


#admin.py

from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Person, Editor, Author

admin.site.register(Person)
admin.site.register(Editor)
admin.site.register(Author)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are two things here-

1. **DB schema** - The table structure generated in the DB.
2. **Django Admin panel** - How these models are represented in django admin panel.

   - Now you said that with current implementation (inheriting `Person`) the DB structure is being generated fine, i.e. "`Editor` and `Author` classes make `Person` their FK".
   - What's happening here is that django admin is just looking at the model structure for processing them (CRUD operations), which is why you are getting all the fields instead of dropdown to `Person` in admin panel.

One way to solve it would be to manually add FK instead of using inheritance-

```
class Editor(models.Model): 

    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    years_experience = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        fullname = self.lastname + ', ' + self.firstname[0]+'.'
        return fullname.encode("utf-8")

class Author(models.Model): 

    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __str__(self):
        fullname = self.lastname + ', ' + self.firstname[0]+'.'
        return fullname.encode("utf-8")
```

**Note:- Also, you should use inheritance for common fields (such as `active`) through abstract model. Docs:- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes**

Comment: it works, but is there a way to do this using inheritance? i.e still have to inherit from Person class?